# Debian/Installer Preseed Remove Post Install Kernel Options + Multi NIC Preseed Tip

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, automation, grub, preseed

In light of recent automation trends, I would like to be able to fully automate an install of Ubuntu.  My my first problem was auto selection of the bootif with multiple NICs break Ubuntu/Debians preseed very badly.  I ended up fixing that with the following kernel options.

```
ksdevice=bootif  
netcfg/link_wait_timeout=10 
netcfg/dhcp_timeout=60 
netcfg/choose_interface=auto 
auto-install/enable=true
```

(Hope that part helps someone we work mostly with RedHat distros so I spent a good part of a month going from zero to get to this point for Ubuntu... among other projects.)

That being said.  I was able to fully automate the install!!! YAY... except... the new issue is that when the system restarted I had no display.

With some research I discovered that it is likely a hardware/kernel driver module unavailability issue for the graphics... since this is a server graphics are not my concern at the moment.  I chose to insert the `debian-installer/add-kernel-opts string nomodeset` option to offset this.

Unfortunately this didn't work.  I further discovered that while this did not work it was because I still have the "default" `splash` and `quiet` kernel options being enabled.

holding shift during boot allows me to get into the grub boot loader and change this temporarily.  As such I was able to verify that removing these two options does indeed fix the issue.

Sorry for the long winded wind-up, essentially my question is how do I remove the default kernel options from being installed on an Ubuntu system during preseed when I cannot run scripts against the `/target/` system. ??

Answer (score 0):

With preseed, you can execute a `late_command` that will be executed at the end of the installation process.

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target wget -P /tmp/ $server/script.sh; in-target chmod $+x /tmp/script.sh; in-target /tmp/script.sh
```

Basically, you just have to modify the kernel options of the target system.

Hope it helped !